# ArgumentError in SongsController#create missing required :bucket option

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-4

I've been trying to get paperclip working with amazon s3 all day and I'm gettin' pretty close.

Albeit, how do I get around this error? I've included the bucket in the song model so I'm not sure what it's asking for. Once this is solved it should work.

**Error:**

```
ArgumentError in SongsController#create
missing required :bucket option


    respond_to do |format|
      if @song.save
        format.html { redirect_to @song, notice: 'Song was successfully created.' }
        format.json { render action: 'show', status: :created, location: @song }
      else
```

**song.rb**

```
class Song < ActiveRecord::Base

  acts_as_voteable

  belongs_to :user
  has_many :comments, :dependent => :destroy
  has_many :genre_songs
  has_many :genres, through: :genre_songs

has_attached_file :track,
 :storage => :s3,
  :path => '/:class/:attachment/:id_partition/:style/:filename',
  :url => ":s3_domain_url",
  :bucket => ENV['bucketname']


  validates_attachment :track, :presence => true

  validates_presence_of :url

  validates :title, length: { minimum: 10 }
  validates :url, length: { maximum: 300 }

  def self.tagged_with(name)
    Genre.find_by_name!(name).songs
  end

  def tag_list
    genres.map(&:name).join(", ")
  end

  def tag_list=(names)
    self.genres = names.split(",").map do |n|
      Genre.where(name: n.strip).first_or_create!
    end
  end
end
```

**paperclip.rb**

```
# config/initializers/paperclip.rb 
Paperclip::Attachment.default_options[:url] = ':s3_domain_url'
Paperclip::Attachment.default_options[:path] = '/:class/:attachment/:id_partition/:style/:filename'
```

**production.rb and development.rb**

```
config.paperclip_defaults = {
    :storage => :s3,
    :s3_credentials => {
      :bucket => ENV['my bucketname'],
      :access_key_id => ENV['my access key'],
      :secret_access_key => ENV['my secret access key']
    }
  }
```

**show.html.erb**

```
<p id="notice"><%= notice %>


    <p>
    <%= @song.title %> | ( <%= @song.url %> )

    <br />
    <span class="subtext"><span class="votes_<%= @song.id %>"><%= pluralize(@song.votes.count, 'like') %>,</span>
    posted <%= time_ago_in_words(@song.created_at) + " ago" %>
    <small><span class="comments"></small> | <%= pluralize(@song.comments.size, 'comment') %></span></small><br /></span></span>
    </p>

    <p>
    <%= audio_tag (@song.track.url), controls: "controls", alt: "Please use chrome, ie, or safari", preload: :auto %>   
    </p>
    <p>Genres: <%= raw @song.genres.map(&:name).map { |t| link_to t, genre_path(t) }.join(', ') %></p>
    <%#= link_to 'Show', song, class: "button small secondary" %>
    <%= link_to('Edit', edit_song_path(@song), class: "button small secondary") if can? :update, @song %>

    <%#= link_to 'Back', songs_path,  class: "button small secondary" %>

<br /><br />


    <%= render :partial => 'comments/form' %>
    <div class="replies">
    <% unless @song.comments.empty? %>
      <h5><%= pluralize(@song.comments.size, 'comment') %></h5>
    <br />
    <% end %>

    <% if @song.comments.empty? %>
    <p>There are no comments...</p>

    <% else %>


     <div id="comments">
      <% for comment in @song.comments %>
        <div class="comment">
          <strong><%= link_to_unless comment.site_url.blank?, h(comment.author_name), h(comment.site_url) %></strong>
          <em>on <%= comment.created_at.strftime('%b %d, %Y at %H:%M') %></em>
          <%=simple_format comment.content %><hr>
          <p>
              <%= link_to("Edit", edit_comment_path(comment)) if can? :update, @comment %>
            <% end %>
              <%= link_to("Destroy", comment, :method => :delete, :confirm => "Are you sure?") if can? :destroy, @comment %>
          </p>

        </div></div>

    <% end %>

</div></div>
```

**song_controller.rb**

```
class SongsController < ApplicationController
  before_filter :authenticate_user!, only: [:create ,:edit, :update, :destroy, :vote_for_song]
  before_action :set_song, only: [:show, :edit, :update, :destroy, :vote_for_song]

  def vote_for
      @song = Song.find(params[:id])
      current_user.vote_for(@song)
      @song.plusminus = @song.votes_for
      @song.save
      respond_to do |format|
        format.js { render 'update_votes' }
      end
  end

  def vote_against
    @song = Song.find(params[:id])
    current_user.vote_against(@song)
    respond_to do |format|
      format.js { render 'update_votes' }
    end
  end

  def new_songs
    @songs = Song.order "id DESC"
  end


  # GET /Songs
  # GET /Songs.json
  def index
    if params[:genre]
      @songs = Song.tagged_with(params[:genre]).paginate(:page => params[:page], :per_page => 15)
    else
      @songs = Song.order('plusminus').paginate(:page => params[:page], :per_page => 15)
    end
  end

  # GET /Songs/1
  # GET /Songs/1.json
  def show
   @comment = Comment.new(song: @song) 
  end

  # GET /Songs/new
  def new
    @song = Song.new
  end

  # GET /Songs/1/edit
  def edit
  end

  # POST /Songs
  # POST /Songs.json
  def create
    @song = Song.new(song_params)

    respond_to do |format|
      if @song.save
        format.html { redirect_to @song, notice: 'Song was successfully created.' }
        format.json { render action: 'show', status: :created, location: @song }
      else
        format.html { render action: 'new' }
        format.json { render json: @song.errors, status: :unprocessable_entity }
      end
    end
  end

  # PATCH/PUT /Songs/1
  # PATCH/PUT /Songs/1.json
  def update
    respond_to do |format|
      if @song.update(song_params)
        format.html { redirect_to @song, notice: 'Song was successfully updated.' }
        format.json { head :no_content }
      else
        format.html { render action: 'edit' }
        format.json { render json: @song.errors, status: :unprocessable_entity }
      end
    end
  end

  # Song /Songs/1
  # Song /Songs/1.json
  def destroy
    @song.destroy
    respond_to do |format|
      format.html { redirect_to songs_url }
      format.json { head :no_content }
    end
  end

  private

    def set_song
       @song = Song.find(params[:id])
     end

     def song_params
       params.require(:song).permit(:title, :artist, :url, :track, :user_id, :tag_list)
     end
  end
```

Comment: How are you including the ENV variables?

Comment: maybe that's what I'm missin' but I would imagine in the production.rb and development.rb

Comment: @TheIrishGuy what should I do here? :)

Comment: Hwo did you set your  `env variables`?

Comment: I set the env variables using: $ heroku config:set AWS_BUCKET=your_bucket_name
$ heroku config:set AWS_ACCESS_KEY_ID=your_access_key_id
$ heroku config:set AWS_SECRET_ACCESS_KEY=your_secret_access_key

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In dev and prod env you call:

`ENV['my bucketname']`

In model:

`ENV['bucketname']`

Also a good name for env variable would be:

`ENV['MY_BUCKETNAME']`

In your case:

`ENV['AWS_BUCKET']`

`config.paperclip_defaults = { 
      :storage => :s3,
      :bucket => ENV['BUCKETNAME'],
      :s3_credentials => { :access_key_id => ENV['my access key'], :secret_access_key => ENV['my secret access key'] } }`

Comment: thanks @rmagnum2002, although those were just examples to not disclose my real bucket name. The real name is the same for all of the above.

Comment: Got it, also in an app I was working on with amazon uploads I used these S3 configs only in environments files, dev and prod, not in model, in model just added `require 'aws/s3'` at the top of the file

Comment: All that I have in model is has_attached_file and styles for it.

Comment: Try to move out the bucket option out of credentials, place it jus above the credentials starts.

Comment: I just tried the above steps but the files still seem to be uploading to public/assets/system/song for some reason

Comment: May be restart server.  Sounds stupid ;-) . I am typing on tab and can't do very much on it to help you out.

Comment: Np :) I'm getting this error again after restarting: "server missing required :bucket option." I'll look into the documentation some more.

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/34667/discussion-between-rmagnum2002-and-apane101)