# Rails "missing required :bucket option" w/ AWS S3 + Paperclip -- image upload works on Heroku but not locally

Tags: ruby-on-rails, amazon-web-services, heroku, amazon-s3, paperclip

I've been trying to make Paperclip (gem version 4.2) work with amazon s3 (gem version 1.66) in a simple blog for two days and would appreciate any advice you all can provide.

Everything works fine on Heroku--the images upload to my bucket and display correctly--but locally I'm getting the error "missing required :bucket option" when I try to attach an image to an article.

What am I missing here?

I've tried the solutions in [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13444264/aws-s3-paperclip-missing-required-bucket-option) and [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18004249/argumenterror-in-songscontrollercreate-missing-required-bucket-option) and [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23108589/rails-paperclip-missing-required-bucket-option) and [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18794779/rails-paperclip-s3-argumenterror-missing-required-bucket-option) related SO post with no luck.

Thanks.

**production.rb and development.rb**

```
config.paperclip_defaults = {
    :storage => :s3,
    :s3_credentials => {
      :bucket => ENV['S3_BUCKET_NAME'],
      :access_key_id => ENV['AWS_ACCESS_KEY_ID'],
      :secret_access_key => ENV['AWS_SECRET_ACCESS_KEY']
      }
    }
```

**env.rb**

```
ENV['s3_bucket'] = 'edited_mybucketname'
ENV['aws_access_key_id'] = 'edited_myaccesskey_id'
ENV['aws_secret_access_key'] = 'edited_mysecretkey'
ENV['AWS_REGION'] = 'us-east-1'
```

**aws.rb**

```
AWS.ACCESS_KEY_ID = ENV["AWS_ACCESS_KEY_ID"]
AWS.SECRET_ACCESS_KEY = ENV["AWS_SECRET_ACCESS_KEY"]
AWS.REGION = ENV['AWS_REGION']
S3.BUCKET_NAME = ENV["S3_BUCKET_NAME"]
```

**_form.html.erb**

```
<%= form_for @article, html: {multipart: true} do |f| %>

  <% if @article.errors.any? %>
    <div id="error_explanation">
      <h2>
        <%= pluralize(@article.errors.count, "error") %> prohibited
        this article from being saved:
      </h2>
      <ul>
        <% @article.errors.full_messages.each do |msg| %>
          <li><%= msg %></li>
        <% end %>
      </ul>
    </div>
  <% end %>

  <p>
    <%= f.label :image %><br>
    <%= f.file_field :image %>
  </p>
  <p>
    <%= f.label :title %><br>
    <%= f.text_field :title %>
  </p>

  <p>
    <%= f.label :text %><br>
    <%= f.text_area :text %>
  </p>

  <p>
    <%= f.submit %>
  </p>

<% end %>
```

**show.html.erb**

```
<%= image_tag @article.image.url(:large), :class => "img-responsive" %>
```

**Gemfile**

```
source 'https://rubygems.org'
ruby '2.3.0'

gem 'rails', '4.2.2'

gem 'pg'
gem 'sass-rails', '~> 5.0'
gem 'uglifier', '>= 1.3.0'
gem 'coffee-rails', '~> 4.1.0'
gem 'jquery-rails'
gem 'turbolinks'
gem 'bootstrap-sass', '~> 3.3', '>= 3.3.6'
gem "font-awesome-rails"
gem 'paperclip', '~> 4.2'
gem 'aws-sdk', '~> 1.66'
gem 'simple_form'
gem 'mail_form'
gem 'jbuilder', '~> 2.0'
gem 'sdoc', '~> 0.4.0', group: :doc

group :development, :test do
  gem 'byebug'
  gem 'web-console', '~> 2.0'
  gem 'spring'
end

group :production do
    gem 'rails_12factor', '~> 0.0.3'
end
```

Comment: Did you try adding rails_12factor to development and see if it works?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Case matters with ENV Vars: `ENV['s3_bucket']` (from your env.rb files) is not the same as the `ENV['S3_BUCKET']` call elsewhere.

On Heroku, you can run `heroku config -a your_app_name | grep bucket` to confirm that it is indeed uppercased on Heroku. (Assuming you're on a *nix machine).

Comment: That fixed it! Thank you @M00B!